# Change ctrl+k-o (new project) directory

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

In VSCode, I can type `Ctrl+k-o` to open a new project. It opens the parent directory, so if I'm in `~/dev/PHP`, it opens up for me to pick a project from `~/dev`, then I have to click into `PHP` & then select the project I actually want.

I just want to change it so that `ctrl+k-o` opens my file explorer to the same directory my project is currently open in, instead of the parent

Comment: I have a hacky solution. I use [`Project Manager`](https://github.com/alefragnani/vscode-project-manager) & I have a `PHP` project that points to all my php libs. at `~/dev/PHP`. So I made a symlink at `~/dev/PHP/PHP` that points to `~/dev/PHP` & changed the Project Manager to point to that symlink. So now it opens in `~/dev/PHP/PHP` & I can still see all my projects in the sidebar PLUS if I hit `ctrl+k ctrl+o`, it'll now open in `~/dev/PHP`... which is basically what I want. So hacky. So good <3 Would love a proper solution though.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the `command: workbench.action.files.openFileFolderInNewWindow`.

Navigate to the Keyboard Shortcuts editor of VSCode [(Keybindings)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)

Search for `workbench.action.files.openFileFolderInNewWindow` and override it with your desired keyboard shortcut.

**Or** in the *keybindings.json* file you can add:
`{"key": "[YOUR_SHORTCUT]","command": "workbench.action.files.openFileFolderInNewWindow"}`

Comment: Thank you! :D That is much better. If I have `projectdir/somefile.txt` open & use it, then it opens to `projectdir`. If I have `projectdir/subdir/somefile.txt` open & use it, then it opens to `projectdir/subdir`. I still like that better, because it's easier to navigate upwards. And I think I can figure out how to use that with `multi-commands` extension, or something, to open a file in `projectdir` THEN execute `workbench.action.files.openFileFolderInNewWindow`.

Comment: Do you know where I can see & search all the available commands? I went to that keybindings link and `openFileFolderInNewWindow` isn't listed there. & I've looked around before & can never find a complete resource.

Comment: File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts (Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts on macOS) should do the trick. There you can also search for commands. However, the documentation and searching can be improved I agree. 
(e.g. searching for "dir" or "directory" as i would suggest in your case would leave you unsatisfied)

Answer (score 0):

Open search line with CTRL+SHIFT+P. Search for Preferences: Open keyboard shortcuts (JSON)

[[image: Preferences: Open keyboard shortcuts (JSON)1]

You can write the following binding:

```
[
  { "key": "ctrl+n", "command": "explorer.newFile", "when": "explorerViewletFocus" }
]
```

[image: You can write the following binding:]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's not what I'm looking for, but the keyboard-shortcuts gave me a kicking off point. There's a package called multicommands that I could probably configure to change my current directory in vscode, then execute the `workbench.action.files.openFolder`, but I honestly don't know how to lookup vscode commands. I never have any luck when I try

Comment: Try reading the docs. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings
Sorry i couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: If you are not going to use other folders other than the PHP folder, then maybe try opening your PHP folder rather than your dev folder as the root.